# The way of passing complex params into spring date rest's method

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to find any info regarding the following issue:
I have a JPA repository which was exposed to REST service with Spring Data Rest project:

```
Page<Business> findByUser(@Param("user") User user, Pageable pageable);
```

where the `user` parameter is the entity.

Now when I try to call this REST method from client (with RestTemplate or Traverson) I can't understand how should I pass this param...

Is it possible to implement it without making custom controller?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `User` is another Spring Data REST managed entity? If so you pass a URI identifying the user you'd like to hand into the method to the query method resource.

```
Traverson traverson = new Traverson(…);
traverson.follow("businesses", "search", "findByUser")
  .withTemplateParameters(Collections.singletonMap("user", "…/users/4711")).…
```

Comment: The problem that once I use the format you suggested rest call fails with: `Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.lang.Long for value '.../users/4'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".../users/4"`

Comment: The same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268063/findby-uri-not-working-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: I have the same issue (not using Traverson, but directly hitting my server API).

So I did a little debug, and I've watch what is in `org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter`.  Inside, `info.metadata.idType` is `Long` (which is normal, my @Id is put on a Long), while source is the URI String. And so it try to call for a String -> Long Converter. And this provoke the exception.

I think it is not intended to arrive here, but I can not understand what went wrong on the road...

Comment: and so, if I put the DB id instead of the URI, it does work. But I thought it was not intended to manipulate them.

Comment: by the way, I've put a breakpoint in `org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter` and it never hit. So may be a problem with the registration of this converter ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Look at [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-502) on Spring JIRA.

The way to request this depends on your version of Spring Data Rest. If you have a version 2.4+, you have to use the URI. If you have an older version, you have to use the primary key.

So you may need to expose your primary keys if you have an older version of SDR. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703623/bookmark-angularjs-frontend-direct-access-spring-data-rest-backend) could help you in managing that.